# How to talk to this A/D Converter in Linux (ADS7138)

Tags: linux-device-driver

For a project I'm thinking of using this relatively new IC from TI - the [ADS7138](https://www.ti.com/product/ADS7138?keyMatch=ADS7138&tisearch=Search-EN-everything&usecase=GPN). The issue (I believe, though I may be wrong) is that there is no driver for this chip in the kernel. Does anyone have any suggestions for a work around to talking to this driver? Is there another driver I could use or am I stuck writing a custom driver specific for this IC?

Comment: You can write the kernel driver for everybody and submit it upstream. Just talk about this with IIO maintainers in linux-iio@ mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on a board bring-up project with the same IC. I couldn't find a driver for it so I wrote one myself. I hope it works for you as well:
[ADS7138 Driver](https://github.com/nesteroff/ads7138-linux-driver)

Answer (score 0):

Till you find a compatible kernel driver or develop one yourself, you can quickly experiment with the ADC from user space using the [i2c-tools](https://i2c.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/I2C_Tools). You can use either the command line tools or use the API to write your own app, but be cautious if you use the command line tools like `i2cget(8)`, first read the man pages and pay attention to the **warning** section.

To use the API, `open(2)` the i2c device, set the slave address with `ioctl(2)`, then use smbus APIs like `i2c_smbus_write_word_data()`, `i2c_smbus_read_word_data()` etc. You may take a look at the tools code like *i2cget.c* itself to see how the API is used. Following is a simple code to read a register from an I²C chip connected to /dev/i2c-0.

```c
int fd = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR);
ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, slave_address);
__s32 res = i2c_smbus_read_word_data(fd, register_address);
close(fd);
```

See kernel documentation or the web about [i2c/smbus](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/dev-interface.html) and [instantiating i2c devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/instantiating-devices.html) for more details.